# Как добавить в объект еще один параметр?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Допустим, у нас есть объект с очень большим количеством параметров и функций.

```
var obj = {
    param1: Object,
    param2: Function,
    param3: 'Вообще, что угодно',
    ...
    param_n: 'И еще что-нить'
}
```

Как мне добавить в этот объект еще один параметр?
**PS**:
С использованием библиотеки `ExtJS` либо вообще без библиотек (`native JS`).

Comment: На простом js тут никак, только ExtJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
obj['param125'] = '123';
```

Вариант 2:

```
obj.param125 = '123';
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать вот такое объявление:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.param1 = Object;
obj.param2 = 4;
obj.param2 = true;
```

Comment: `new Object()` и `{}` эквивалентны.